# Creating Environment variables in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to create a custom Environment variables in Jenkins by doing this

List of key-value pairs

Name: Build_Date
Value: Date()

The value part is not resolving to a date - any ideas?

Here is where I am trying to config the above

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm that you can use the EnvInject plugin with a Groovy script:

[image]

Here is the Groovy script:

```
// Generate a global BUILD_ID_LONG variable with date and time
// =======================================

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
def now = new Date()
def map = [BUILD_ID_LONG: now.format("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")]
return map
```

Next, you can use the ${BUILD_ID_LONG} variable in your build steps.